# How to incrementally load , fit with new data , save the pipeline model in using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Any pointers to incrementally train and build the model , and get the prediction on single element.

Trying to run a web application will write data to csv in a shared path , and the ml application will read data and loads the model , tries to fit the data and save  the model , transform the test data. ( This is supposed to happen in loop)

But when  loading the saved model second time , facing following exception ,
(am using a minmax scaler to normalize the data)

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Output column features_intermediate already exists.**

Any pointers would be much appreciated , Thank you

```
object RunAppPooling {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { // start the spark session
        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").set("deploy-mode", "client").set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
      .set("spark.broadcast.compress", "false")
      .setAppName("local-spark")

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()


    val filePath = "src/main/resources/train.csv"
    val modelPath = "file:///home/vagrant/custom.model"

    val schema = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("IDLE_COUNT", IntegerType),
        StructField("TIMEOUTS", IntegerType),
        StructField("ACTIVE_COUNT", IntegerType),
        StructField("FACTOR_LOAD", DoubleType)))
   while(true){
    // read the raw data
    val df_raw = spark
      .read
      .option("header", "true")
      .schema(schema)
      .csv(filePath)

    df_raw.show()
    println(df_raw.count())
    // fill all na values with 0
    val df = df_raw.na.fill(0)
    df.printSchema()

    // create the feature vector
    val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(Array("IDLE_COUNT", "TIMEOUTS", "ACTIVE_COUNT" ))
      .setOutputCol("features_intermediate")

    var lr1: PipelineModel = null
    try {
      lr1 = PipelineModel.load(modelPath)
    } catch {
      case ie: InvalidInputException => println(ie.getMessage)
    }

    import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler
    val scaler = new StandardScaler().setWithMean(true).setWithStd(true).setInputCol("features_intermediate").setOutputCol("features")

    var pipeline: Pipeline = null
    if (lr1 == null) {
      val lr =
        new LinearRegression()
          .setMaxIter(100)
          .setRegParam(0.1)
          .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
          .setLabelCol("FACTOR_LOAD") // setting label column
      // create the pipeline with the steps
      pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array( vectorAssembler, scaler, lr))
    } else {
      pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(vectorAssembler, scaler, lr1))
    }

    // create the model following the pipeline steps
    val cvModel = pipeline.fit(df) 

    // save the model
    cvModel.write.overwrite.save(modelPath)

    var testschema = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("PACKAGE_KEY", StringType),
       StructField("IDLE_COUNT", IntegerType),
        StructField("TIMEOUTS", IntegerType),
        StructField("ACTIVE_COUNT", IntegerType)
      ))

    val df_raw1 = spark
      .read
      .option("header", "true")
      .schema(testschema)
      .csv("src/main/resources/test_pooling.csv")

    // fill all na values with 0
    val df1 = df_raw1.na.fill(0)
    val extracted = cvModel.transform(df1) //.toDF("prediction")
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val test = extracted.select(mean(df("FACTOR_LOAD"))).collect()
    println(test.apply(0))
}
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way at-least to get past away the exception not sure whether it is right apporach or not .Here it goes while creating the pipeline after loading the model , set the stages as only the model , because model has already defined with respective schema . Not sure whether this will normalize the new data or not .

```
  pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array( lr1))
```